# C# IPC Across User Sessions, or similar

Tags: c#, wcf

All systems are Windows 7, programming will be done in C#, targeting .NET 4.5.2.

The goal is to have a core program (I hesitate to refer to it as a service because I don't want to muddy the waters) that runs regardless of what user is logged in to the PC.  The core program will run all the time.  Users will log in (at least to the client program by authenticating against an internal system, if not the PC using Active Directory) and client programs will send and receive data to and from the core program.  Since these PCs are in common areas of a secure facility, they currently auto-log-in as a generic user.  This may or may not change, but the program requirements dictate that they will at least have to log into the client program.

What is the best solution for this scenario?

I had thought this would involve a Windows service and named pipes, but I haven't found a working solution yet.  I have tried several WCF named pipe examples that work wonderfully if both the client and server are in the same user session, but have not found the key to getting them to work across user session boundaries.  Now I'm wondering if I should take advantage of the fact that a generic user is logged in automatically and have the core program run as that user.

This is my first SO question, so Hello World!

[Edit]
The 'core' and 'client' programs will reside on the same PC, there is no need to communicate with the network.  The core will retrieve data from a database and pass data on to a piece of industrial equipment.  The core would also need to receive data from the industrial equipment and communicate that data to any clients that are listening, if any.  It also logs that that data on the PC.  The client program will display the data from the industrial equipment as a chart.  I'm trying to be as clear as I can, but I don't know which pieces are important.

Comment: I think you have a lot of poor assumptions and "requirements" that aren't fully thought through.  There is no reason you can't simply use an HTTP connection between the client and server.  You don't need to use WCF if the communication is simple enough.  There's a lot of ways to go about this, but the proper solution will require far more information than you have provided.

Comment: To run an application all the time  - you definitely need a windows service as your core program. But be aware of that it cannot create any UI. The client can be simple tray application that may start on user login and connect to the service via any of the IPC mechanism.

Comment: Thank you VitaliyK, for confirming that a service is the technology I should be working toward.  Erik may have provided some insight as well, in that I shouldn't necessarily focus on named pipes - there are other options for communication.